# Advanced Cocoa Category - catching all file access - iOS

Tags: objective-c, filesystems, categories

Hey Guys,
 In my app i need to verify that the file actually exist on the device before its being accessed by some file access methods (UIImage imageNamed, Cocos2d CCSprite method and so on).

I need to be sure that the file is on the device (and if not try to fetch it from the servers). 
Can I do it without changing all the code to support it?
I thought on something like a 'Super Category' on the file system...
Is it possible???

I saw this idea, what do you think
[overriding-methods-in-cocoa-without-subclassing](http://www.fousa.be/blog/overriding-methods-in-cocoa-without-subclassing)

Thanks!
 M.

Answer (score 0):

it's often best to attempt the file/url read and fail gracefully - filesystems have a way of changing.

if you know the image's bundle, then use NSBundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:` but from the docs:

> /* The following methods are of limited utility. Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the filesystem or a particular file on the filesystem is encouraging odd behavior in the face of filesystem race conditions. It's far better to attempt an operation (like loading a file or creating a directory) and handle the error gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed.

So probably just try to get the resource, if it fails, fetch and then retry.